# Is it possible to create a safe classloader in Java?

Tags: java, classloader, securitymanager

I plan on allowing users of my program to create their own subclasses to use as modules in my program. I've always read that classloaders were insecure, and I completely understand why. What I want to know is if I'm able to use something similar to SecurityManager to allow loading a class, but restricting its access to other packages within the project, and the jdk. My users should only need certain libraries to create their modules, but I cannot just have them injecting malicious code into the program.

Is it possible to use SecurityManager or something similar to do this?

Comment: 1. By default, the security manager doesn't disable class loading.  2. Class loading is "insecure" because it allows anyone to execute arbitrary code.  As long as you trust your users, it's safe enough.

Comment: I don't trust my users though. I would like to be able to restrict access to certain classes. I trust the majority of my users, but I am aware of a few that are not so trustworthy.

Comment: There you should not allow any code to be executed, classes or otherwise.  There's no way to make this 100% safe.  I guess that's your answer: no you can't make arbitrary code execution safe; there's always risk.

Comment: I'd imagine reflection may be an answer. I feel like there may still be a way to do this.

Comment: Instead of letting users add arbitrary Java classes to your program, you better create a domain specific language and let them create "plugins" with that.

Comment: That’s exactly what `SecurityManager` was made for. Explaining the concepts is way too broad for a Q&A and there are documentation and tutorials about this topic. The short answer is, yes it’s possible to use a `SecurityManager` to restrict the permissions for code loaded from a specific source (or better the other way round, allow permissions for your application and the JRE only), as that’s the primary purpose of it.